# python. beautifulsoup. Не получается получить все ссылки со страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Не могу вытащить все ссылки на карточки ЖК, получается вытащить только 1 ссылку с помощью `find`

на сайте код выглядит так :

```html
<div data-name="Container" data-mark="GKCardTitle" class="_0fce717cdb--container--1Gxqr _0fce717cdb--container-background_color--transparent--3pvxk _0fce717cdb--container-display--inline-block--3bIEb" style="padding:4px 12px 0 0"><a target="_blank" title="" data-mark="Link" **href="https://zhk-evropeyskiy-krasnodar.cian.ru/"** class="_0fce717cdb--element--2vdm4">
<span data-name="Text" data-mark="Text" class="_0fce717cdb--element--1dA0Y _0fce717cdb--element-color--blue--qwziq _0fce717cdb--element-display--inline--1FKwo _0fce717cdb--element-font_weight--bold--1L-ao _0fce717cdb--element-word_wrap--normal--3wgcE _0fce717cdb--element-white_space--normal--3WKkF _0fce717cdb--element-font_size--18--B8Elb _0fce717cdb--element-line_height--22--38O8Y _0fce717cdb--element-color_hovered--red--OpS-L">ЖК «Европейский»</span></a></div>
```

ссылка на саму страницу: https://krasnodar.cian.ru/novostroyki

Методом find с уточнением

```
soup.find('div', class_='class="_0fce717cdb--container--1Gxqr _0fce717cdb--container-background_color--transparent--3pvxk _0fce717cdb--container-display--inline-block--3bIEb").find('a').get('href')
```

работает и находит необходимую ссылку

Но методом find_all не получается добиться нужного результата.

Comment: имена классов - динамические, там нет одинаковых `_0fce717cdb--container--1Gxqr...`

Comment: У вас разные имена классов в ссылках, вот и не получается найти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://krasnodar.cian.ru/novostroyki/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

cards = soup.find_all('div', {'data-mark': 'GKCard'})

for card in cards:
    title = card.find('span', {'data-mark': 'Text'}).text
    link = card.find('a', {'data-mark': 'Link'})['href']
    print(f'{title} {link}')
```

выведет на печать:

```
ЖК «Европейский» https://zhk-evropeyskiy-krasnodar.cian.ru/#map
ЖК «Самолет» https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-samolet-krasnodar-353100/hod-stroitelstva/
ЖК «Сказка град» https://zhk-skazka-grad-krasnodar.cian.ru/hod-stroitelstva/

...

ЖК «Резиденция» https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-rezidenciya-kozhzavod-mkr-7135/hod-stroitelstva/
ЖК «Седьмой континент» https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-sedmoy-kontinent-krasnodar-8390/otzyvy/
ЖК «Южане» https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-yuzhane-krasnodar-23921/hod-stroitelstva/
```

Comment: Благодарю. Способ помог - немного поправил теги.
Понял принцип. Буду тщательнее изучать вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag

response = requests.get('https://krasnodar.cian.ru/novostroyki')
soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

def link_from_header(header: Tag):
    a = header.find('a')
    return a.get('href')


link_list = [*map(link_from_header, soup.find_all('div', {'data-mark': 'GKCardTitle'}))]

print(*link_list, sep='\n')

# https://zhk-evropeyskiy-krasnodar.cian.ru/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-samolet-krasnodar-353100/
# https://zhk-skazka-grad-krasnodar.cian.ru/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-park-pobedy-krasnodar-1686651/
# https://zhk-strizhi-krasnodar.cian.ru/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-abrikosovo-krasnodar-16066/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-elegant-krasnodar-8304/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-dostoyanie-krasnodar-1789905/
# https://zhk-sportivnaya-derevnya-krasnodar.cian.ru/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-otkrytie-krasnodar-50168/
# https://zhk-gubernskiy-krasnodar.cian.ru/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-rakurs-krasnodar-1659959/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-dyhanie-krasnodar-39245/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-development-plaza-krasnodar-144280/
# https://zhk-sportivnyy-park-krasnodar.cian.ru/
# https://zhk-melodiya-krasnodar.cian.ru/
# https://zhk-solnechnyy-gorod-krasnodar.cian.ru/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-novella-krasnodar-1706586/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-svoboda-krasnodar-33666/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-lime-krasnodar-1276272/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-serdce-shkolnyy-mkr-47259/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-grani-krasnodar-48852/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-rezidenciya-kozhzavod-mkr-7135/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-sedmoy-kontinent-krasnodar-8390/
# https://krasnodar.cian.ru/zhiloy-kompleks-yuzhane-krasnodar-23921/
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. 
Не все понял.  но постараюсь разобраться

Comment: @K1bomax, `link_list = [*map(link_from_header, soup.find_all('div', {'data-mark': 'GKCardTitle'}))]` Если нужен список ссылок с которым нужно дальше работать

Comment: Да я понял.  но у меня пока что все идет без функций.  решил написать одной простыней. После буду переписывать по человечески.

Comment: @K1bomax, `[*map(lambda x: x.find('a').get('href'), soup.find_all('div', {'data-mark': 'GKCardTitle'}))]` И функцию можно убирать,

Comment: Понял,  принял, Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь собрать все 'div' по тегу data-mark="GKCardTitle" и из них вытягивать значения. Используя регулярные выражения можно достать все необходимые названия:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://krasnodar.cian.ru/novostroyki/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('div', {"data-mark" : "GKCardTitle"})
matches = re.findall(r'(?<=data\-name\=\"Text\"\>)(.*?)(?=\<\/span\>)', str(divs))
print(matches)
#['ЖК «Европейский»', 'ЖК «Самолет»', 'ЖК «Сказка град»', 'ЖК «Парк Победы»', 'ЖК «Стрижи»', 'ЖК «Абрикосово»', 'ЖК «Элегант»', 'ЖК «Достояние»', 'ЖК «Спортивная Деревня»', 'ЖК «Открытие»', 'ЖК «Губернский»', 'ЖК «Ракурс»', 'ЖК «Дыхание»', 'ЖК «Development Plaza (Девелопмент Плаза)»', 'ЖК «Спортивный парк»', 'ЖК «Мелодия»', 'ЖК «Зеленодар»', 'ЖК «Novella (Новелла)»', 'ЖК «Свобода»', 'ЖК «LIME (ЛАЙМ)»', 'ЖК «Сердце»', 'ЖК «Грани»', 'ЖК «Резиденция»', 'ЖК «Седьмой континент»', 'ЖК «Южане»']
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. 
Понял принцип.